# Are there OpenSea Webhooks for monitoring NFT collections?

Tags: javascript, ethereum, webhooks, opensea

Does OpenSea have a webhook API for sales of a given Ethereum NFT collection? I see they have a streaming JS API which uses websockets but I can't seem to find a server oriented API.

They [posted a reply to someone on Twitter in 2018](https://twitter.com/apiopensea/status/1071990003910279170?lang=en) about clicking "More" then "Subscribe" on a collection webpage to setup a webhook but it seems this functionality has disappeared.

If not, is it possible to use their websockets JS api on a server (as opposed to a browser)?

And if that's not possible does anyone know of a solution to this problem (receiving POST requests on a server when transactions of a given NFT contract occur)?